# How can i figure out if a virtual kernel address is valid?

Tags: linux-kernel

Is there any way a driver can check if a given virtual address is mapped and can be dereferences?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are having trouble executing some system calls that are expecting userspace addresses. We don't really need to check if a address is valid in this case -- in fact, we need to do the opposite: prevent the failure mechanism from engaging.

From [Kernel System Calls by Alessandro Rubini](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/ksys/)

> Like any other function that transfers data to/from user space using a
>   user-provided pointer, the system call checks whether the provided
>   buffer is a valid address or not. During normal operation, an address
>   that lies in the user address range (0-3GB for standard kernel
>   configuration) is considered valid, and an address that lies in kernel
>   address space (3GB-4GB) is not.

You can use the macros `get_ds`, `get_fs`, and `set_fs` together to define the highest virtual address that is to be considered valid, thus allowing you to pass kernelspace addresses to system calls.

```c
mm_segment_t fs = get_fs();        /* save previous value */

set_fs (get_ds());                 /* use kernel limit */

/* system calls can be invoked */

set_fs(fs);                        /* restore before returning to user space */
```

1. First we save the current configuration using the `get_fs` macro.
2. Next we use the `set_fs` macro to set a new upper limit.

   - The `get_ds` macro provides the maximum possible virtual address for the kernel.
3. All kernel addresses are now valid.

   - This configuration lasts until the next `set_fs`.
   - Invoke as many system calls as your heart desires without fear of failure from the usual userspace address checks.
4. Finally we use `set_fs` macro to return the limit to the previous configuration.

**Important**: Make sure to return the limit to the previous configuration (where only userspace addresses are valid); otherwise, an invalid pointer passed from userspace could cause havoc in your driver!

Comment: thanks for the informative answer. I've found the function __virt_addr_valid which tells me if the page that the address lies within is mapped.